# Can't import .vue component into javascript file because of MIME type

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to import a .vue component into my javascript file, but it keeps throwing the error:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

The project is being done with laravel.
Folder structure:

```
Laravel-app/
├─ resources/
│  ├─ views/
│  │  ├─ index.blade.php
├─ public/
│  ├─ js/
│  │  ├─ main.js
│  │  ├─ component.vue
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
import component from "./component.vue";

let vm = new Vue({
el: "#app",

components: {
    component
  }
});
```

component.vue file:

```
<template>
<div> 
   <p>Hello</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "component",

    data: function() {
        return {
            toggle: false
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The browser can't normally directly use `.vue` files. You should use laravel-mix as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#vue)